# How to make my phone number bold using css

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and am trying to use css to bold my phone number listed in this contact information.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of what to use?
Thank you for your help in advance.

```html
<div id="contact_info">
 <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
 <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd  love to hear from you!</p>
 <p>Phone: 0064 1122334455</p>
 <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make text bold in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082353/how-do-i-make-text-bold-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** Wrap telephone number in `b` or `strong` tag.

```html
<div id="contact_info">
  <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
  <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd 
    love to hear from you!</p>
  <p>Phone: <strong>0064 1122334455</strong></p>
  <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
</div>
```

**Method 2:** Wrap in an inline element like `span`, apply a class and style in css with `font-weight: bold` property.

```css
.tel {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact_info">
  <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
  <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd 
    love to hear from you!</p>
  <p>Phone: <span class="tel">0064 1122334455</span></p>
  <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use **Bold** Tag like this `<b>0064 1122334455</b>` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<b>` or `<strong>` tag like below;

```
 <div id="contact_info">
                        <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
                        <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd 
                            love to hear from you!</p>
                            <p>Phone: <b>0064 1122334455</b></p>
```

OR

```
 <div id="contact_info">
                            <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
                            <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd 
                                love to hear from you!</p>
                                <p>Phone: <strong>0064 1122334455</strong></p>
                                <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to use **CSS** `font-weight` property.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.normal {
    font-weight: normal;
}

p.light {
    font-weight: lighter;
}

p.thick {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p.thicker {
    font-weight: 900;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="normal">Hello</p>
<p class="light">Hello</p>
<p class="thick">Hello</p>
<p class="thicker">Hello</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `b` tag to make text bold.
Or use css to set styles for this element.

```html
    <div id="contact_info">
        <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
        <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I
        have been working on, I'd love to hear from you!</p>
        <p>Phone: <b>0064 1122334455</b></p>
        <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
  <p><strong>Phone: 0064 1122334455</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `<strong>`

```html
<div id="contact_info">
                    <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
                    <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd 
                        love to hear from you!</p>
                        <p><strong>Phone: 0064 1122334455</strong></p>
                        <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **bold** tag

```
<p>Phone: <b>0064 1122334455</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) field in CSS:

```
.bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

and add a span tag surrounding the phone number:

```
<div id="contact_info">
    <h3><a id="contact">Contact</a></h3>
    <p>If you are interested in chatting or want more information on what I have been working on, I'd 
    love to hear from you!</p>
    <p>Phone: <span class='bold'>0064 1122334455</span></p>
    <p>Email: tracyexcell@email.com</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:    `<p><b> Phone: 0064 1122334455 </b> </p>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13125713)

Comment: @H. Pauwelyn , i was just trying to keep the answer very simple .. a  <b>..<b/> will solve his problem right ?? !! anyway, thanks for feedback..i will keep that in mind...

Comment: @Aj1991: sorry I haven't read the question. I didn't know that it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsfiddle.net/75nwgqop/

#phoneNumber {
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

Provide the paragraph tag an id 'phoneNumber'. Then in the css file just add font-weight property to the id 'phoneNumber'.