# Bold text using html

Tags: html

I am tring to do some text display bold in web with HTML.

```html
<p>HELLO</p>
```

My Required output is :- **HELLO**.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make text bold in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082353/how-do-i-make-text-bold-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

You can bold a text in multiple ways.
Way 1:

```
<strong>This text is bold</strong>
```

Way 2:

```
<p>Your username for your new computer is <b>JohnAppleseed</b></p>
```

Way 3 (Using CSS):

```css
p.thick {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p.thicker {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<p class="thick">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="thicker">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Resources you can follow to learn more [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp) [TutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-make-text-bold-in-HTML#:%7E:text=To%20make%20text%20bold%20in%20HTML%2C%20use%20the,strong%20importance%20to%20the%20text.)

Answer (score 0):

`strong` is the HTML tag to do that. Refer to `W3Schools`.

```html
<strong>HELLO</strong>
```